# How can I modify mongo query for limited values using push function

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I have a following  Mongo query which is giving me result like the screen shot .
how can I modify the query to limit the number of values in nodes array.

Gor example I want only top 3 values in my nodes array.[image]

```
{ $group: {
        _id: "$url",
        nodes: { 
            $push: { 
                totaltime: "$totaltime",

        },

        },  
            },
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You got 4 items just because you have 4 different kinds of `url` field within your collection in mongodb.

To change the amount of `nodes` you might want to play with `_id` param inside `$group`

Comment: so  here the result means 4 diffferent items has same kind of url. What I wantt here is even if the same url have any number of node items, I always get some certain limit of node item say $limit=3